# How to Ensure Input from URL isn't from a Redirected Page

Tags: java, url, redirect

I have the following lines of code that gathers the source code from a given URL:

```
URL url = new URL(websiteAddress);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();  // throws an IOException
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutInMilliseconds);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    outputString += line;
}
```

However, the problem that I'm having is that wi-fi hotspots often redirect you to a page where you have to click "I Agree." If you run this code before you have clicked that checkbox, then it gathers the source code from the hotspot login page, rather than the intended page.

What I want to do is have some way of checking whether or not the intended page was reached. I was hoping that calling `connection.getURL()` after creating the InputStreamReader would show me the actual web page that was arrived, but no such luck. How can I determine whether or not the intended URL has been redirected?

Comment: It probably depends on how the hotspot does the redirect. Using a http redirect, using DNS spoofing, etc. each variant probably has a different method of being detected. E.g. try resolving 3 different domain names, if they all return the same IP address, you're probably not yet beyond the login page.

Comment: Which variant would your solution fix? And how would this be accomplished in code?

Comment: I didn't make this an answer for a good reason ;) Btw. did you analyze the responses from the hotspots? I could also imagine they send some http header indicating the redirection. Mind that some smartphones or OSes handle auth requests from hotspots very specifically.

Comment: I didn't try analyzing anything about the connection because I didn't know what to look for. I assumed you could have Java follow a redirected URL though and then just check if it's equal to what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if the URLConnection handles redirects. I remember that I had to explicitly (or at least was able to) configure redirect behavior in the Apache HTTP client (Java library).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to look for any specific element in your `web` page, and if its not there then you know that you may be in some other page (possibly redirected to some login page).

Comment: This works, but I won't always have control over the pages. I'll need a solution that will work with any page.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to have a server where you know what the response is, and query that first to ensure connectivity to at least that server.  That will (typically) be enough to assume full connectivity.

You can then go on to query the url you're interested in.

The challenege is that if a computer asks for the page at some url, the way a lot of wifi hotspots work is to intercept that request and return the page.  There's often no clue, form the computer's POV that the page returned is not the page requested.

Comment: When the page is returned, would the URL of the page be returned with it? Surely it would have to if a browser displays it.

Comment: Depends on how the wifi works.  If it's intercepting any request, and sending back a redirect to the wifi page, then it's detectable.  If it's simply returning itself in the DNS query, and then serving up its page regardless of the path, then no, it's not detectable.

Comment: So if it is in the former category, what can I do in code to detect it?

Comment: Assuming the url is http(s), you would see a 3xx response code (most likely a 302).

Comment: Alright, so what do I do in code to detect a 3xx response code?

Comment: You'll need to incorporate an http package such as apache commons http.  The docs for whatever package you choose can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to call [`setFollowRedirects(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29).  By default, a connection will quietly follow redirects and try to reach a page which returns a `200` HTTP response.  Disabling redirect following will make confirming the expected page is returned easier, simply confirm the response is a `200`.

That said, @rec's comment is worth taking into account - it isn't enough to simply check the response code, because there are many different ways a router could interrupt your request, many of which are not detectable.  A malicious router could, for instance, intercept all your requests and change the responding content in a subtle but dangerous way - this is called a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

By definition you cannot avoid MitM attacks unless you can open a secure and trusted connection (generally, HTTPS) between yourself and the remote site, however assuming you aren't really concerned about attacks, the better tactic is simply to assume the data you get back could be broken in any number of ways, and instead make your scraping logic more robust to that possibility.

I can't speak directly to *how* you would make your logic more robust without understanding your use case and the issues you've run into, however the gist would be to add checks where issues might arise, and throw an exception that you then handle gracefully higher up the stack.

For instance, if your code was:

```
System.out.println(outputString.subString(outputString.indexOf('A'));
```

This would fail if `outputString didn't actually have an`'A'` character.  So check that explicitly:

```
int aPos = outputString.indexOf('A');
if (aPos < 0) {
  throw new InvalidParseException("Didn't find an 'A', cannot proceed");
}
System.out.println(outputString.subString(aPos);
```

And handle the `InvalidParseException` wherever makes the most sense for your use case.